# Building a select Option with variables

Tags: jquery

I'm building a set of options for my dropdown list using the key, value pairs in a dictionary.

```
for(var key in times_dictionary) {
   var title = times_dictionary[key];   
   $("#id_booking_time").append('<option value="key">title</option>');
}
```

The above code doesn't work. How do I actually insert the 'key' as each option's value and each "title" as the item that will be shown to the end user for each option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Concat properly

```
for (var key in times_dictionary) {
  var title = times_dictionary[key];
  $("#id_booking_time").append('<option value=' + key + '>' + title + '</option>');
}
```